# python tkinter Radiobutton

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this python script.I cannot found what mistake i done.can anyone tell me what mistake i done in this program?

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
v=IntVar()
s=IntVar()
def sel():
 x=v.get()
 if x==1:
    l2.config(text="correct")
 else:
    l2.config(text="wrong")
  z=s.get()
  if z==1:
    l3.config(text="correct")

 else:
    l3.config(text="wrong")
l=Label(root,text="what is 2 + 2 ?")
l.pack(anchor=W)
R1=Radiobutton(root,text="4",variable=v,value=1)
R1.pack(anchor=W)
R2=Radiobutton(root,text="5",variable=v,value=2)
R2.pack(anchor=W)
l2=Label(root)
l2.pack()
l2=Label(root,text="what is 5 + 9?")
l2.pack(anchor=W)
R3=Radiobutton(root,text="14",variable=s,value=1)
R3.pack(anchor=W)
R4=Radiobutton(root,text="5",variable=s,value=2)
R4.pack(anchor=W)
l3=Label(root)
l3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the  goal of your program?

Comment: I want to print on label "write/wrong" after the per question..but its doesnt print when i clicked on radiobutton

Comment: Why do you think the radiobutton knows which function to call when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided source code are missing links between `Radiobutton` and the function `sel()` which manages selected `Radiobutton`. Other misunderstandings and erroneous declarations are blocking the display of 'correct/wrong'.

**Error 1** - to manage `Radiobutton` changes, each control shall be linked with the checking function.

To call the function `sel()`, add a `command` on each `Radiobutton`.

```
R1=Radiobutton(root,text="4",variable=v,value=1,command = lambda : sel())
...
R2=Radiobutton(root,text="5",variable=v,value=2,command = lambda : sel())
...
R3=Radiobutton(root,text="14",variable=s,value=1,command = lambda : sel())
...
R4=Radiobutton(root,text="5",variable=s,value=2,command = lambda : sel())
```

**Error 2** - In the `sel()` function, check the `value` instead of using a simple `if-else`.

> The function `sel()` is called at each `Radiobutton` change. If no
>   `Radiobutton` is selected, the returned value of `InVar()` is `0`.

```
def sel():
    x=v.get()
    if x==1: # value of R1
        l2.config(text="correct")
    elif x==2: # value of R2
        l2.config(text="wrong")
    z=s.get()
    if z==1: # value of R3
        l3.config(text="correct")
    elif z==2: # value of R4
        l3.config(text="wrong")
```

**Error 3** - the variable `l2` is used to display 'correct/wrong' of the first question and to display the second question.

> Rename the second `l2` to `lQ2` to prevent change in `sel()` function.

```
R2=Radiobutton(root,text="5",variable=v,value=2,command = lambda : sel())
R2.pack(anchor=W)
l2=Label(root)
l2.pack()
lQ2=Label(root,text="what is 5 + 9?")
lQ2.pack(anchor=W)
R3=Radiobutton(root,text="14",variable=s,value=1,command = lambda : sel())
R3.pack(anchor=W)
```